# Firefox and Semantic UI React: display problems of modal windows

Tags: reactjs, firefox, iframe, modal-dialog, semantic-ui

I am developing a web application using React and Semantic UI React as a front-end framework. The application is tested and works in Chrome, Microsoft Edge, Safari and Mozilla Firefox. However in this last browser I noticed a problem with iframes. The image below shows a modal window with iframe with a pdf. The window opens correctly but as soon as I try to click inside it or scroll the pdf downwards, the modal window is displayed incorrectly.

I tried to identify any problems in the rendered HTML code using the Firefox developer tools (F12)  but I didn't notice anything.
 
I am using Firefox v77.0.1 64bit (latest version) and the modal window is implemented as follows:

```
        <Modal closeIcon open={this.state.open} onClose={this.onClose}>
            <Modal.Content>
                <Steps ... />
                
                <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "500px" }}>
                    <Iframe url={...} width={"100%"} height={"460px"} />
                    <Checkbox ... />
                </div>
            </Modal.Content>

            <Modal.Actions>
                <Button color='red' onClick={this.props.onRefuse}>
                    <Icon name='remove' />
                    Refuse
                </Button>
                <Button color='green' onClick={this.props.onAccept}>
                    <Icon name='check' />
                    Accept
                </Button>
            </Modal.Actions>
        </Modal>
```

[image]